# AutoCompleteTextView select problem

Tags: android

I want to know if this is possible using Android's XML:
I have AutoCompleteTextView and I want by default that I have some text inside ( I set `android:text="test"` and connect in Activity to adapter) but when user start typing to automatically delete "test" and start print inside autocomplete user inputs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `android:hint="test"` within the XML for that text view.